# How to display data only authorized user?

Tags: node.js, angular

How to implement a function to display data only authorized user (make as a profile). Tell me what and how to fix it so that the data will be displayed by an authorized user.

Nodejs:

models:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define('users', {
        login: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(40),
            required: true,
            unique: true
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            required: true,

        },
        roles: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            required: true
        },
        full_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(100),
            required: true
        },
        photoSrc: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING(200),
            default: ''
        }
    })
    return User
}
```

user.controller:

```
const db = require('../database/database')
const User = db.users

module.exports.authUser = async function(req, res) {
    try {
        const users = await User.find({user: req.user.id})
        res.status(200).json(users)
    } catch(e) {
        errorHandler(res, e)
    }
}
```

routes:

```
const express = require('express')
const controller = require('../controllers/user')
const passport = require('passport')
const router = express.Router()

//http://localhost:5000/api/users/
router.get('/', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), controller.authUser)

module.exports = router
```

After the user has logged in and tried to open  profile, an error is displayed in the terminal:

> TypeError: User.findById is not a function

```
  const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy
    const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt
    const User = require('../models/User')

    const options = {
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(), 
      secretOrKey: process.env.SECRET_OR_KEY
    }

    module.exports = passport => {
      passport.use(
          new JwtStrategy(options, async (payload, done) => {
              try {
                  const user = await User.findById(payload.userId).select('login id')

                  if (user) {
                      done(null, user)
                  } else {
                      done(null, false)
                  }
              } catch(e) {
                  console.log(e)
              }
          })
      )
    }
```

Angular 6:

service:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from "../interfaces";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UsersService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    fetch(): Observable<User[]> {
       return this.http.get<User[]>('/api/users/')
    }

}
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../shared/services/users.service';
import { Category } from '../shared/interfaces';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users-page',
  templateUrl: './users-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users-page.component.css']
})
export class UsersPageComponent implements OnInit {

  users$: Observable<User[]>

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService,) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.users$ = this.usersService.fetch() 
  }

}
```

component.html:

```
  <div class="row" *ngIf="users$ | async as users">
      <div class="col s12">
          <div class="collection" >
              <a *ngFor="let user of users" class="collection-item">{{user.full_name}}</a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: what database and ORM are you using ?

Comment: @bereketgebredingle database PostgreSQL and ORM Sequelize

Comment: Ok.. so I think `findById` is not a method in seqeulize model. So change it with find and where clause. `User.find({
        where: {
           id: payload.userId
        }....`

Comment: @bereketgebredingle the error is just the same instead of "User.findById" error "User.find"

Comment: can u show me the model's code ?

Comment: @bereketgebredingle added to the question

Comment: Hmmm... I can't c erroneous code. But on the user controller u used `db.User` so hv u tried to use this thing also in the JWT strategy code ?

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure the parent component gets a value that is the decision maker as far as permissions/authorizations go, and make sure to use this value together with CanActivate, or CanActivateChild directives which are a great technique offerered by Angular for authorization strategies.